# Can't get videos with 4k or 1080p higher with youtubeextractor

Tags: c#, youtube, resolution

I am making one app for downloading videos from Youtube and other features, but for now I have problem with download 4k videos. I don't know why but when I try to download video which support 4k resolution, it's always app stop working..

```
/*
* Select the first .mp4 video with 360p resolution
*/
VideoInfo video = videoInfos
   .First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && info.Resolution == 360);

/*
* If the video has a decrypted signature, decipher it
*/
if (video.RequiresDecryption) {
    DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
}

/*
 * Create the video downloader.
 * The first argument is the video to download.
 * The second argument is the path to save the video file.
 */
var videoDownloader = new VideoDownloader(video, Path.Combine("D:/Downloads", video.Title + video.VideoExtension));

// Register the ProgressChanged event and print the current progress
videoDownloader.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.ProgressPercentage);

/*
 * Execute the video downloader.
* For GUI applications note, that this method runs synchronously.
*/
videoDownloader.Execute();
```

This is the example from nuget `YoutubeExtractor`. I make modifications to get highest resolution from video, but when the video is 4K, the app is dying.

Comment: What does dying mean? Did you get an exception?

Comment: It says that "An unhandled .NET Framework exception occured in App.exe[492]."

Comment: Then debug it .. where does the problem happen when you debug it - it will stop on a line

Comment: When i debuged it, it says that downloader.Execute();

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Is the `VideoDownloader` your code or from the NuGet package?

Comment: Also, what modifications are you making?  Show us your code, since the example presumably works.